# Component's async setup function not being called in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a component. something like `<Component></Component>`. In that component file I have an async setup function something like this:

```html
<template>
  <!-- stuff -->
</template>

<script>
export default defineNuxtComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            // ...
        };
    },
    
    async setup() {
        console.log("setup");
    }
});
</script>
```

If I include that component in another component I would expect that setup function to be called and "setup" to appear in the console. However, no setup function is called. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Edit: I just noticed, if I change something in the file and Nuxt does some hot reload, then the setup functions are called.

Comment: Did you try to use `Suspense` component in the parent one. Here is official docs https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#basic-usage

Comment: no, i did not use it